# SweetAlert2 Display out put from a Directive (Angular 4/5/6)

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular5, sweetalert, sweetalert2

Im using a custom directive to diplay QRcode on my site, i want the QR code to display on a sweetalert2 pop up.

I've tried to address it like:

```
Swal({title: 'HTML <small>QR Code</small>!',
      html: '<qrcode></qrcode>'
              });
```

But the up doesn't display the output produced by the directive

Note: I have rested the QRcode directive without the pop up and it works fine.

Any help on this matter is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately sweetalert does not support custom html selector in `html` property yet, if you are using angular 6 then you can use angular elements to export the directive or component as a custom html element so that it can be used anywhere in your app irrespective of the root component (even directly in index.html)